# Sqoop cannot find mysqldump when using direct import into HDFS

Tags: hdfs, mysql, sqoop

I'm new to the whole Hadoop stack so please bear with me.

I'm trying to import a whole table from MySql into HDFS using Sqoop 1.4.5 and I believe I have everything setup correctly but then Sqoop is telling me this:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I can import without the --direct command but for some reason it can't find mysqldump.

Need help on this, please!

PS: I googled for a whole day and nothing could show me the right path.

PS2: I'm using a single node distribution on a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysqldump utility is used with the "direct connector". The reason it cannot be found is that the mysqldump binary is either not on your system or not part of the PATH environment variable when Sqoop is running the MapReduce job. Things that will help:

1. It seems like you're running mac, so try installing MySQL with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install mysql`.
2. Try `which mysqldump` to find the mysqldump utility. If you can find it this way, then you may have a special PATH for your user. I'd try creating a soft link in /usr/bin via `ln -s $(which mysqldump) /usr/bin/mysqldump`. Otherwise, uninstall MySQL and install it over homebrew.

Comment: Creating a soft link did the work for me! I was getting desperate because I did have mysql installed but didn't know why it couldn't find it.

Comment: can you help me because when I do 2n2 way, it failed, ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/mysqldump’: File exists  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy mysqlinsert and mysqldump in the path in all nodes and it will work.

[Here you can find a reference](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sqoop-user/201307.mbox/%3C20130717164511.GD15412@localhost%3E)

In my case, I execute on each worker a pair of commands

```
sudo scp mysqlserver:/usr/bin/mysqlimport /usr/bin/
sudo scp mysqlserver:/usr/bin/mysqldump /usr/bin/
```

Now both files are on the path on all workers, I can execute the sqoop command again and it works.

Kind regards